# Select a specific number of items from an array/hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm using the Koala gem to attempt to implement a search functionality for my own Facebook friends in a web app.

The built in search functionality of the gem does not, so far as I have found, give me the option to search just friends for matches. So I'm attempting to implement a search using this method.

`hash.select { |key, value| value["gender"] == "female" }.to_a.sample(100)`

I want to select and display only 100 users per page or less. Is there a better way to do this rather than the above method?

Comment: why are you using `sample`, `Enumerable#each_slice` seems to be what you need here

Comment: sample will select 100 random value from this hash. you can use limit while fetching the data use `hash.select { |key, value| value["gender"] == "female" }.to_a.first(100)`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice),

Using this you can iterate over your search results in chunk of n elements.

```
(1..10).each_slice(3) {|a| p a}
# outputs below
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10]
```